# how to Search List with Comma Separated values in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list and want to find values in it. Search text to find the values will be in Comma separated string.

Input:

```
var students = new List<Student>() { 
                new Student(){ Id = 1, Name="One"},
                new Student(){ Id = 2, Name="Two"},
                new Student(){ Id = 3, Name="Three"},
                new Student(){ Id = 4, Name="Four"},
                new Student(){ Id = 5, Name="Five"}
            };
```

Search Text:

```
var searchString = "Two,Three";
```

Output:

```
{Id = 2, Name="Two"},
{Id = 3, Name="Three"}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it give you the desired result?

Comment: Use an array of values instead of a string with comma-separated values. With a `string[] names` the query will be a simple `students.Where(st=>names.Contains(st.Name))`. Split the string to get a string array

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd split the search string and put the values into a HashSet:

```cs
var searchValues = new HashSet<string>(searchString.Split(','));
```

Next, check if the elements match, for example using LINQ:

```cs
var filteredStudents = students.Where(s => searchValues.Contains(s.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: Answering "write code for me" questions without any indication of research or experiment effort or clear problem statement is somewhat frowned upon. OP did not disclose what keeps him from coming up with a solution.

Comment: As a side note you may consider using the overload for compared and explizites define the comparer you want to use. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-6.0#properties to maybe enable `One` being equal to `one`

Comment: And you may want to use a combination of stringsplitoptions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0#fields to support `Two, Three` (notice the whitespace after the `,`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, standard loops, raw code,  you have this;

```
        var students = new List<Student>() {
            new Student(){ Id = 1, Name="One"},
            new Student(){ Id = 2, Name="Two"},
            new Student(){ Id = 3, Name="Three"},
            new Student(){ Id = 4, Name="Four"},
            new Student(){ Id = 5, Name="Five"}
        };

        string searchString  = "Two, Three";

        searchString = searchString.Replace(" ", ""); // remove blanks

        foreach (Student OneStudent in students)
        {
            foreach (string OneSearchItem in searchString.Split(','))
            {
                if (OneStudent.Name == OneSearchItem)
                {
                    Debug.Print(OneStudent.Id.ToString() + " , " + OneStudent.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Not pretty - but shows looping, and how to pick apart each item.

Next up, a linq expression.

```
        List<Student> MyFoundList = new List<Student>();

        foreach (string OneSearchItem in searchString.Split(','))
        {
            List<Student> MyFind=
                 students.FindAll(mystudents => mystudents.Name.Equals(OneSearchItem));

            MyFoundList.AddRange(MyFind);
        }

        // display all results
        foreach (Student OneStudent in MyFoundList)
            Debug.Print(OneStudent.Id.ToString() + " , " + OneStudent.Name);
```

So, I would go with the 2nd.

I "think" there is a relative clean and readable way to pass the search part a "list", and thus even the for/each for the split on search terms could be dropped (would be happy if shown how this is possible).

However, I think the above is readable enough - and easy to adopt.